# kotlin reject negative, string and float input

Tags: kotlin

I'm not allowed to change the `toIntOrNull()` and I need to reject every string, float, and negative input. I tried to do it with `n is String` but I just encountered and error. Is there any other way to do it?

Here's my code:

```
fun main(){
    print("Enter number of numbers from Fibonacci: ")
    var n: Int? = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    
    //print("Input is Invalid!")
    var total = fib(n)
    print("Total $total")
}
```

An example of what should appear when a string, double or negative is entered:

```
Enter number of numbers from Fibonacci: one
Input is Invalid!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("Enter number of numbers from Fibonacci: ")
var n: Int? = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()

if (n != null && n >= 0) {
  // if n is not null, then n is an Int (because of toIntOrNull() above)
  val total = fib(n!!)
  print("Total $total")
} else {
  print("Input is Invalid!")
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `!!` on `n` after the null check I believe, smart cast should take care of it

Comment: @lukas.j Thanks for this! It worked with the string and double, but when I tried it with a negative number (ex: -2), the output was still `Total 0`. Any suggestions with it?

Comment: @Joffrey: It's a _var_ (it could of course be a _val_).

Comment: @PoohSan: then change the condition to _if (n != null && n >= 0) { ..._

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a `var` since it's a local variable that never escapes the function scope. Smart-casting will work. You're already utilizing smart-casting in the `n >= 0` expression.

Comment: The smart cast doesn't work in case of a var. _Error: 'Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'n' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time'_

Comment: It compiles fine without `!!`. It doesn't make sense that it would give that error for the second use of `n` but not for `n >= 0`, or that it would call it a property in the error message when it's not a property. https://pl.kotl.in/-Ynj4eoO7

Comment: I have the error in the IDE and it prevents execution (in a scratch file).

Comment: Yes, the error disappears if I move the code into a main() function in the scratch file.

Comment: Kotlin scripts are weird--all defined `val`s and `var`s and locally defined functions are treated as if defined at the top level of a class as member properties and member functions. Still, you should have been getting that same error for `n >= 0`.